# Find ${(ab)}^{-1}$ if $a^2=e, b^6=e, ab=b^4a$ where $a,b$ are elements of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If $a,b$ are elements of a group and $a^2=e, b^6=e, ab=b^4a$, then find the order of $ab$ and express ${(ab)}^{-1}$ in terms of $a^mb^n$ and $b^ma^n$

I could find the order of $ab$ to be 6 but struggling to find ${(ab)}^{-1}$ in terms of $a^mb^n$ and $b^ma^n$.

Please help me move forward.

Comment: Hint: $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$.

Comment: Hint: Compute $$(ab)(b^5a)$$

Comment: To be sure, it's only possible to show that the order of $ab$ is a *divisor* of $6$, since it's possible, for instance, that $a=b=e$. (This could be ruled out by saying "the order of $a$ is $2$ and the order of $b$ is $6$" instead of "$a^2=e$ and $b^6=e$.")

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in hints beneath the OP,

$$(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}=b^5a$$

which gives the inverse in the form $b^ma^n$.  To get it in the form $a^mb^n$, use the equation $ab=b^4a$ to obtain

$$(ab)^{-1}=(b^4a)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-4}=ab^2$$

**Added later**: It's worth noting that $(ab)^{-1}=ab^2=b^5a$ implies $(ab)^{-2}=(ab^2)(b^5a)=aba$ and hence (using what the OP found, namely $(ab)^6=e$)

$$e=(ab)^{-6}=(aba)(aba)(aba)=ab^3a$$

from which it follows that $b^3=e$, so the order of $b$ is not $6$. (This was found by orangeskid in more direct fashion.)

Answer (score 1):

We have 
$$b = a b^4 a = (a b a)^4= (b^4)^4=b^{16}= b^6 \cdot b^6 \cdot b^4 = b^4$$
so $b^3=e$ and $ab= b a$. From here it is easy to see that the order of $ab$ is $\le 6$  (it is in fact the product of the orders of $a$, $b$, these being relatively prime). Moreover, $(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}=a b^2= b^2 a$.

Comment: Or, $b = a^{-1} b^4 a$ implies $o(b)=o(b^4)$ and so $\gcd(o(b),4)=1$,which gives $o(b)=1,3$. Also, it is possible that $o(b)=1$.

Comment: @lfh: totally right!  For  they may  all be equal to $e$.  Corrected in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

With the information given, you could actually simplify the powers of $ab$ in succession

$(ab)^2 = b^4a\cdot ab = b^5$
$(ab)^3 = ab\cdot b^5 = a$
$(ab)^4 = a\cdot ab = b$
$(ab)^5 = ab\cdot b = ab^2$
Also $(ab)^5 = b\cdot b^4a = b^5a$
And finally  $(ab)^6 = b^5a\cdot ab = b^6=e$ meaning that $(ab)^{-1} = (ab)^5$

[However, also $(ab)^3 = b^5\cdot b^4a = b^3a$ which gives us $b^3=e$, but using that might confuse whoever is marking the question]

Comment: Ha, and everyone else comes to the same conclusion about $b^3$.